# On the individual contributions that lead to Poincaré–Birkhoff–Witt Theorem (History)

Tags: lie-algebras, math-history

The theorem in the Title includes three mathematicians; but the papers where written independently (see the Wikipedia page corresponding to the above theorem).

Can anybody *state* what results were proved by whom, I will at proofs for them if necessary, according to the context?

The History in Wikipedia discusses only naming of the theorem, but not how the general statement of the theorem came with the work of three people.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74923/so-did-poincar%c3%a9-prove-pbw-or-not, https://mathoverflow.net/a/112392/27465. As far as I understand, it's not like each of them contributed parts to a proof, but each of them gave a complete proof, independently and without knowing the work of the others; although for Poincaré it's contested that his proof is complete.

Comment: Maybe the question is better suited for https://hsm.stackexchange.com?